# Intent filter for gallery

Tags: android, intentfilter

I want my application to show in the phone's gallery share dialog only. So not in the share dialog of other applications.

The file paths of the images always seem to look like this: content://media/external/images/media/1234

I tried the following:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:pathPattern="media/external/images/media/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

For some reason, my app doesn't show up in the image gallery's share dialog. What has to be changed to make it work?

Comment: "I want my application to show in the phone's gallery share dialog only" -- there are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. Those models will have hundreds of different gallery apps. There is no single `<intent-filter>` that guarantees that all of those apps will show your app as a share option and no other app will show your app as a share option. With respect to your current problem, add a leading `/` to your `pathPattern`.

Comment: Unfortunately, a leading slash doesn't help. The application is still not shown. I have to remove scheme, host and pathPattern to make it work. But then, of course, the application is shown everywhere.